# Confusion With MySQL ID IN ('')

Tags: mysql

i am using a mysql query to get data for multiple turnk id. But i getting different result for different format for IN (). 
My ID formats:

```
    1) IN ('1,2,3')
    2) IN ('1','2','3')
    3) IN (1,2,3)
```

By applying those formats i am getting result from mysql but each time it is displaying different result. It is not random. suppose by:
 using no. (1) i am getting  55 and 
 using no. (2) i am getting  87 and 
 using no. (3) i am getting  55

```
 i am not much familiar with this situation. so need your help.
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the format of the ID column? i.e. is it an int?
Some sample data from your table could be handy too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for 3 different things

```
1) IN ('1,2,3')
```

You are querying for the string '1,2,3', it's the same as `ID = '1,2,3'`.

```
2) IN ('1','2','3')
```

You are querying for any of the 3 **strings** '1', '2' and '3', it's the same as `ID = '1' or ID = '2' or ID = '3'`

```
3) IN (1,2,3)
```

You are querying for any of the 3 **numbers** 1, 2, and 3, it's the same as `ID = 1 or ID = 2 or ID = 3`

Normally 2) and 3) would give the same result as implicit conversion between strings and numbers would yield the same values.

Comment: Don't you mean 2) and 3) would yield same result?

Comment: i am getting same result for 1) and 3) and 2) is returning different result

Comment: understand the issue. Thanks